# Why should I manually name foreign key constraints?

Tags: foreign-key, naming-convention

I see people talking about the best way to name foreign key constraints.  I have never manually named them, I just get whatever my RDBMS gives it, like `tableName_ibfk_1`.  If I've never seen a need to name them, should I care about this?  Why do some people care?

Answer (score 3):

People care because constraint violations typically display the constraint name, and so it's helpful to know that you violated a constraint called, eg `fk_person_state` rather than one called `person_ibfk_1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever refer to FKs in manually written maintenance scripts (less common these day as many frameworks do a lot of this sort of thing automagically, but far from rare) it is useful to follow a consistent naming convention that you and your team find easy to remember and work with.

Naming then yourself avoids potential consistency issues if a future DB version/variant/drop-in-replacement has a different heuristic for determining the name if your don't specify one.